# Последовательность выполнения методов при помощи анотаций и рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в задании.

Есть класс с набором методов, которые отмечены аннотациями. Аннотации `@Test`, `@BeforeSute` и `@Aftersute` создаем, сами указав в последних двух параметр `int value()` - для указания приоритета выполнения метода.

Нужно создать класс со статическим методом, который принимает как параметр объект типа `Class` и запускает методы, отмеченные `@Test`-аннотацией, при этом метод с аннотацией `@BeforeSute` выполняется первым, потом метод с `@Test`, а последний с `@Aftersute`-аннотацией.

Пока выходит только запуск всех методов, отмеченных `@Test`. Как сделать так, чтобы методы выполнялись в нужном порядке? Мне советуют добавить их в приоритетную очередь (закомментировал в коде `PriorityQueue`), но я не пойму, как это сделать.

Ниже привожу свой код.

Класс с методами:

```
public class ClassTest {

@Test
@AfterSuite(value = 2)
public void load() {
    System.out.println(" LOAD method ! ");
}

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println(" TEST method ! ");
}

@Test
@BeforeSuite(value = 5)
public void print() {
    System.out.println(" PRINT method ! ");
}

public void noAnnotation () {
    System.out.println(" This method has no annotation ! ");
}
}
```

Анотации:

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

public @interface Test {
}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

public @interface BeforeSuite {
    int value();
}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)

public @interface AfterSuite {
    int value();
}
```

И класс запуска методов:

```
public class TestRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException,
        NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException {
    ClassTest classTest = new ClassTest();
    Class clazz = classTest.getClass();
    start(clazz);
}

public static void start(Class c) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException,
        NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException {
    Object o = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
    Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
  //  Queue<Method> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for (Method m : methods){
         Annotation[] annotations = m.getDeclaredAnnotations();
         for (Annotation a : annotations){
             if (a.annotationType().equals(Test.class)){
                     m.invoke(o);
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: А если у метода 2 аннотации - например, `Test` и `BeforeSuite`, - то это значит, что он должен будет выполниться два раза? Сначала в очереди `BeforeSuite`, потом в очереди `Test`?

Comment: Я так понимаю Test - это маркер, т.е. если есть у метода такая анотация то метод входит в очередь выполнения. А BeforeSuite и AfterSute определяют приоритет выполнения методов : BeforeSuite - первый в очереди,   AfterSute - последний, а между ними методы отмеченные просто Test.

Comment: А разве не могут быть несколько методов помечены просто как `Test`? Ведь в таком случае их тоже можно различать по `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось так:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException,
            NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException {

        start(ClassTest.class);

    }

    public static <T> void start(Class<T> c) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException,
            NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException {

        Constructor<T> constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
        T o = constructor.newInstance();
        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();

        Queue<Method> queue1 = new PriorityQueue<>(
                (m1, m2) -> Integer.compare(m2.getDeclaredAnnotation(BeforeSuite.class).value(),
                        m1.getDeclaredAnnotation(BeforeSuite.class).value())
        );
        Queue<Method> queue2 = new PriorityQueue<>(
                (m1, m2) -> Integer.compare(m2.getDeclaredAnnotation(Test.class).value(),
                        m1.getDeclaredAnnotation(Test.class).value())
        );
        Queue<Method> queue3 = new PriorityQueue<>(
                (m1, m2) -> Integer.compare(m2.getDeclaredAnnotation(AfterSuite.class).value(),
                        m1.getDeclaredAnnotation(AfterSuite.class).value())
        );
        
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getDeclaredAnnotation(Test.class) != null) {
                if (method.getDeclaredAnnotation(BeforeSuite.class) != null) {
                    queue1.add(method);
                } else if (method.getDeclaredAnnotation(AfterSuite.class) != null) {
                    queue3.add(method);
                } else {
                    queue2.add(method);
                }
            }
        }

        Method m;
        while ((m = queue1.poll()) != null) {
            m.invoke(o);
        }
        while ((m = queue2.poll()) != null) {
            m.invoke(o);
        }
        while ((m = queue3.poll()) != null) {
            m.invoke(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то имеется три очереди:

- для `@BeforeSuite`
- для `@Test`
- для `@AfterSuite`

Для каждой аннотации создаём очередь с приоритетом, при этом компаратор делаем такой, чтобы он сортировал в обратном порядке, ведь первыми должны выполняться те методы, у которых `value()` у аннотации больше.

Если у метода есть аннотация `@Test`, то делаем следующие проверки: если у него есть `@BeforeSuite`, то помещаем в очередь для неё, если есть `@AfterSuite`, то для неё, и, наконец, если их нет, то это значит, что есть только `@Test`, так что помещаем метод в очередь для неё.

Так как компараторы были заданы с самого начала, то методы во всех очередях будут отсортированы по `value()` своих аннотаций.

Так что вызываем последовательно методы из `queue1`, `queue2` и `queue3`.

Помимо этого, исправил работу с `Class`, чтобы не использовалась его "сырая" форма, а также объект создаю посредством класса `Constructor`.

Comment: Спасибо большое . Помогло в понимании